# Assign to a property of a pointer of a struct in Go Lang

Tags: go

I'm getting the following error
**Cannot use '"No 3A4"' (type string) as type *string in assignment**

How can I add a default value for the query doesn't return rows so I can't use the row.Scan() function, sample code below.

```
func (orders *Orders) getOrderStatus() {
    var err error
    for _, order := range *orders {
        row := db.QueryRow("SELECT status FROM mss_orders WHERE externalorderkey = ? ORDER BY tipo ASC LIMIT 1", order.PoNumber)
        err = row.Scan(&order.Status)

        if err != nil {
            &order.Status = "No 3A4"    <----- How can I do this?
        }

        fmt.Printf("%+v\n", order)
    }
}
```

Comment: `&order.Status = "No 3A4"` doesn't make sense in this case, just use `order.Status = "No 3A4"`. While you need to pass a pointer to the Scan method (`row.Scan(&order.Status)`) for it to be able to "mutate" the order's Status, you don't need to do that when you have access to the `order` value as you already do inside the loop's scope. Don't confuse the two.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error, we know that `&order.Status` is type `*string`.  Yet you're trying to assign it a value of type `string`.  You could make a pointer to the string instead:

```
str := "No 3A4"
&order.Status = &str
```

Or you could just assign to order.Status directly:

```
order.Status = "No 3A4"
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the field is of type `*string` you have to assign a pointer to a string. That cannot be done on a single line:

```
s := "No 3A4"    
order.Status = &s
```

Alternatively change the value that order.Status is pointing to:

```
order.Status = new(string)
*order.Status = "No 3A4"
```